# Assigning the id in html through the Blade concept. laravel 5.1

Tags: html, laravel-blade

here is my code ,
I want to change the radio buttons,label which is associated with the radiobutton id="male". I have tried various ways to do it, but i can't make it work. I want to change the text "Male" in the label associated to the radio button in **Blade Laravel 5.1**

```
{!! Form::label('gender','Gender') !!} :

{!! Form::label('lblMale','Male') !!}
{!! Form::radio('sex','male' !!}

{!! Form::label('lblFemale', 'Female') !!}
{!! Form::radio('sex',  'female') !!}
```

its working properly , but i want on clicking on male label male check box should check and clicking on Female label it should select female checkbox in blade

Answer (score 0):

you can do radio button like this in laravel blade

```
<label  for="male">
  <input name="male" id="male" value="male" type="radio">
  Male
</label>
<label for="female">
  <input name="female" id="female" value="female" type="radio">
  Female
</label>
```

For this html you can use this code in blade

```
 {{ Form::label('male', 'Male') }}
 {{ Form::radio('sex', 'male', array('id'=>'male','label'=>'female')) }}

 {{ Form::label('female', 'Female') }}
 {{ Form::radio('sex', 'female', array('id'=>'male','label'=>'female')) }}
```

Comment: I used above code but its returning me -> <label for="male">Male</label> <input checked="checked" name="sex" type="radio" value="male"> <label for="female">Female</label> <input checked="checked" name="sex" type="radio" value="female"> -> some like that. so i used {!! !!} instead {{ }} , then its showing me OP but on clicking male label the radio button is  not selecting i have to click on that particulate radio button.

Comment: No error is not their ! but if i click on Male (Label) the male radio should selected and if i click on Female then Female radio should be selected.